# NodeJS Express 正規表現 何桁でもパスが通ってしまう

Tags: node.js, 正規表現

URLが

```
// http://wonderland.com/street/愛媛県
app.get(/^\/street\/.{1,50}$/)
console.log(req.params[0])
// 愛媛県
// パスが通る
```

となる場合はOKですが、
下記のようにもし`/id/数値`が入っていても処理するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

```
// http://wonderland.com/street/Улаанбаатар/id/1230515654
app.get(/^\/street\/(.{1,50}$)(\/id\/([0-9]{1,3}$))?$/)
console.log(req.params[0])
// Улаанбаатар/id/1230515654
// 4桁以上でもパスが通ってしまう
```

やりたいことは

```
/street/(記号以外の日本語や英語、数字、外国語50文字以内)
/street/(記号以外の日本語や英語、数字、外国語50文字以内)/id/(数字3桁)
```

です。なるべくセキュアにしたいのですがstreetのあとの文字列は\w{1,50}では都合がわるかったのでドットを使用しました。

> `\w`  
>   単語に使用される任意の文字と一致します。アンダースコアも含まれます。'[A-Za-z0-9_]' と同じ意味になります。
>
> `.`
>   "\n" を除く任意の 1 文字に一致します。'\n' など、任意の文字と一致するには、'[.\n]' などのパターンを指定します。

また、正規表現を使うとややこしうなるので`req.params.name :name`などは使用しておりません。

Comment: セパレータが `/` ですので、`/^\/street\/([^/]{1,50})(\/id\/([0-9]{1,3}))?$/` とするとか。

Comment: 解決しました！回答いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

※ コメント欄からの転記になります(一部文言を変更)

セパレータが `/` ですので、

```
/^\/street\/([^/]{1,50})(\/id\/([0-9]{1,3}))?$/
```

としてみてはどうでしょう。

Comment: 最初の方に`.`を入れてしまったことにより、残りの文字列を`.`で解釈してしまったため、数字が何桁でも通ってしまったんですね。